# get valueof child node from marklogic document

Tags: xml, marklogic

I have a document which has many XML documents with this hierarchy:

```
<envelope>
 <headers>1211</headers>
 <instance>
   <info xmlns:es="http://marklogic.com/entity-services">
     <title>main document</title>
     <version>1.0.2</version>
   </info>
   <Firstdocument xmlns="http://nl.abnamro.com/cre">
     <mainId>0500910197</mainId>
     <mainIdType>flowchart</mainIdType>
     <contact>
       <contactId>
         <value>1120721</value>
         <scheme>main schema</scheme>
       </contactId>
     </contact>
   </Firstdocument>
 </instance>
 <attachments></attachments>
</envelope>
```

I have updated the actual document. I have similar documents in my database of MarkLogic. How can I return all uris where the `value` = 1120721?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for when you say "the value of child node"? Do you mean `/parent/child/value` producing "112072A", or do you mean all of the text in the `child` element: "12072a AAB credit relationship contact identifier"? And are you looking to obtain that value for all docs in the database, or what?

Comment: I want to return all the documents that have child = "112072A"

Comment: Please update your question to reflect what you are looking for.  this makes the post useful as a reference to others in the future.  1. place your comment in the actual question that reflects you need to return documents and not just values. 2. change the title to reflect the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have updated your question with a different XML structure, I suspect that the issues you have been having are that you are not taking into account the namespaces that your elements are bound to.

Since namespace-prefixes are not being used, it can be very easy to overlook and not realize that the elements are bound to a namespace, or which one is in scope.

In your example XML, the `value` element is a descendant of `Firstdocument`, which is bound to the `http://nl.abnamro.com/cre` namespace.

```
<Firstdocument xmlns="http://nl.abnamro.com/cre">
```

So, in order to search the database for docs with that element and the value "1120721", you need to declare that namespace and use it when constructing the QName:

```
declare namespace cre = "http://nl.abnamro.com/cre";
cts:search(doc(), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("cre:value"), "1120721"))
```

Comment: This does not return any document although i have a document in which a child node is hanve value 112072A.  to note - child node is further down in  heirarchy  of xml.